# Openstack heat-get server_id from stack

Tags: openstack

How can I get `server_id` after creating `stack` via [this](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/orchestration/v1/?expanded=#create-stack) api?

Comment: If you mean the ID of an instance launched by your stack, start with [openstack stack resource list](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/plugin-commands/heat.html#stack-resource-list). I am not sure, off-the-cuff, if you need to follow up with an `openstack stack resource show`.

Comment: @berndbausch Thank you so much. My problem was solved.